# issue with factory_girl , rpsec 2.0 and rails 3.0 => can't get has_one relation working nicely together!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm running rails 3.0, rspec 2.0 and factory_girl. Here is the simplified scenario I'm working with: a user can subscribe to only one plan at a time

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :plan
  attr_accessible :login, :plan_id

end

# plan.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :plan
end

# user_factory.rb
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.login "test"
  u.association :plan
end

#plan_factory.rb
Factory.define :plan do |p|
   p.name "plan1"
end
```

when I run rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb I got this error:

**Failure/Error: user = Factory(:user)
     SQLite3::ConstraintException: users.plan_id may not be NULL**

```
#spec/models/user_spec.rb
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe User do
  it "should be valid" do
    user = Factory(:user)
    #User.new.should be_valid
    user.should be_valid
  end
end
```

what I'm doing wrong? I'm stuck with this very simple scenario, and it is very frustating. at that point BDD slow me down like hell!

Comment: did you build your testing db? `rake db:test:prepare`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user subscribes to one plan. so a user has one plan and a plan is related to many users. So I think I got it right. the error was in the user factory.
replacing

```
u.association :plan
```

by

```
u.association :plan, :factory => :plan
```

fixed the issue.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've implemented the `has_one` association incorrectly. The foreign key in a `has_one -- belongs_to` relationship should go in the table corresponding to the model with the `belongs_to` directive. Check `db/schema.rb` -- I think you'll find that `plan_id` is defined in the `users` table. If you want the `User` model to have one `Plan`, you'll need to remove `plan_id` from `users` and add `user_id` to `plans`.

If you'd rather make it so a `Plan` has one `User`, keep the schema as is and put `has_one :user` in `Plan` and `belongs_to :plan` in `User`.